# React Native - How to get the measures of renderItem in Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I have a horizontal `Flatlist` where items can be of different heights. How can I get the height of all elements or a specific visible element and, depending on the element's height, change the height of the `Flatlist`?

I made a code close to mine on [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/Ck1xLTtcl). In the example, the height in `data` is indicated for the example, **in my code I DON'T KNOW this height**.

I would be very grateful for your help!

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');

const Item = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View style={{width, height: item.height, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
          <Text>{item.type}</Text>
          <Text>{item.text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
};

export default function App() {
    const data = [
        {
            height: 100, //FOR EXAMPLE
            type: 'row 1',
            text: 'row 1'
        },
        {
            height: 200, //FOR EXAMPLE
            type: 'row 2',
            text: 'row 2'
        },
        {
            height: 150, //FOR EXAMPLE
            type: 'row 3',
            text: 'row 3'
        },
    ];

    return (
      <View>
          <FlatList
            style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <Item item={item} />
            )
            }
            horizontal
            pagingEnabled
          />
      </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your main goal here but assuming that you what all items to be the same height (given by the item with the biggest height), you can use `onLayout` to get the highest value. Something like this:

```js
const Item = ({ item, height, setHeight }) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{ width, height: height, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}
      onLayout={({ layout }) => (onLayout.height > height ? setHeight(layout.height) : false)} // If current item height is bigger then the rest, update height for all of them
    >
      <Text>{item.type}</Text>
      <Text>{item.text}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const [itemHeight, setItemHeight] = useState(0) // Keep track of height
  // ... data

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Item item={item} height={itemHeight} setHeight={setItemHeight} />
        )}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

you can try to use `itemHeight` on the FlatList as well and see how that plays out.

Comment: I need the height of the `Flatlist` to be dependent on the height of the currently visible item and change dynamically. If you look at the [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/Ck1xLTtcl) example, you will see that the `Flatlist` is marked in `red` and the item is marked in `yellow`. Here I need the height of the `Flatlist` to be equal to the height of the item and, accordingly, there is no extra red color